# JavaScript: convert string literal to string

Tags: javascript, string, string-literals

I want to convert string literals to strings.

For example:

```
var stringLiteral="\\\" hi world \\\"";
console.log(stringLiteral) //outputs \" hi world \";
var string=convertStringLiteralToString(stringLiteral);
// ^ eval() would be perfect for this were it not horribly slow. <the cake is a lie, guys>
console.log(string); //outputs " hi world "
```

How could I write a function that does this?

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - is there an underlying issue that's led you down this path?

Comment: @JamesThorpe no, I'm trying to log all the strings found in a function (that has been converted into a string.), but at the moment it will log stuff like `the cake is a\\ lie` when I want it to log `the cake is a \lie`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of all possible escaped characters is very short (maybe 7 or 8 characters). Your best option is a simple text replace.

```
string = string
    .replace('\\\"','\"')
    .replace('\\\\','\\')
    /* ... and so on */
```

Note that `eval` is not only slow, but also very dangerous when used against unchecked strings.

Comment: Oh well, I guess I can't expect a convenient automatic thingy for everything. `vote++`